# Why does ChildComponent re-mount instead of re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below (example 1), my understanding is that `ChildComponent` only mounts on the first render of `ParentComponent`. For subsequent renders of `ParentComponent`, `ChildComponent` would simply re-render as well.

```js
const ChildComponent = () => {
  return <div>Hi</div>
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  ...
  return <ChildComponent/>
}
```

In contrast, for the code below (example 2), my understanding is that `ChildComponent` will re-mount every time `ParentComponent` re-renders.

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  ...
  const ChildComponent = () => {
    return <div>Hi</div>
  }
  return <ChildComponent/>
}
```

Why is this? I suspect it's because in example 2, a different instance of `ChildComponent` gets used every time `ParentComponent` renders (i.e. `ChildComponent` has a different reference each time). Is this the right understanding?

Is this behavior documented somewhere? If someone could point me to further reading so I can understand this better, I'd appreciate that too!

Comment: You shouldn't be defining components inside a component ideally

Comment: Your suspicion is spot on. React identifies a component by its reference. So each time it receives a different component it unmounts the old one and mounts the new one. Read the big box labeled "Pitfall" at https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components